# dart is rethrow exception to the calling function

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I have two classes the first is `AppModel` and `AppViewModel`

`AppModel` have a method that do some api operation and return the value according to the state.

`AppViewModel` has a method that calling the `appModel` object method to do the api request.

`AppModel`'s method code is:

```
try {
  final response = await apicall();

  if (response.statusCode != 200)
    return Resource.error(jsonDecode(response.error)['message']);

  return Resource.success(
      ProductDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).productData);
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  print('Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stackTrace');
  return Resource.error(error);
}
```

The problem is when an error has raised the catch method is called as expected and it should return a value to the calling but instead the error is also thrown to the `AppViewModel` function and that cause `an exception is not handled` error.

How to prevent the `AppModel` function from throwing the error to the `AppViewModel` function and instead return the value specified.

The `Resource` class code is :

```
class Resource<T> {

  Resource({@required this.status, this.data, this.message});

  String message;
  Status status;
  T data;

  factory Resource.success(T data) =>
     Resource(status: Status.SUCCESS, data: data);

  factory Resource.error(String msg) =>
     Resource(status: Status.ERROR, message: msg);

  factory Resource.loading() =>
     Resource(status: Status.LOADING);
```

}

Comment: what does Resource.error(error) do?? maybe a error is being thrown by it

Comment: The `resource` class code is added it's only a wrapper